# HTML Absolute element onclick goes back to top of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

im working on a site and I created my own menu for the website.
So the menu is hidden away in 0 opacity and z-index -1.
on button click the menu will show at the screen.

https://williamhrtanto.com/msa/about/ this is the site im working on so you guys can check directly how it currently works

the current problem is that whenever I click on the button to show the menu, it will go back to the top of the page

Im asking on how to wherever i click the menu will show up and wont move back to top of the page.

I've tried with fixed position and absolute position

thankyou

Comment: I think menu is working fine. Problem is only color which is black. Try to change color of menu anchor tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this JS code on your page:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // now you can use jQuery code here with $ shortcut formatting
    // this will execute after the document is fully loaded
    // anything that interacts with your html should go here

    var buttonMenu = $('#menuButtonContainer');
    var menuScreen = $('#menue');

    buttonMenu.click(function(){
        //alert('clicked');
        if(menuScreen.css('opacity')=='0'){
            menuScreen.css('opacity', '1');
            menuScreen.css('z-index', '999');
        }
        else {
            menuScreen.css('opacity','0');
            menuScreen.css('z-index','-1');
        }
    });

}); 
</script>
```

in this place:

```
buttonMenu.click(function(){
    //alert('clicked');
```

change to

```
buttonMenu.click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //alert('clicked');
```

---

note the `e` added as function argument and the new line `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: thankyou ! i add the preventdefault and set the menu to fixed

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove opacity
2. Set display : none, position : fixed
3. After click set display block

Answer (score 0):

You need to cancel the default event of the anchor tag.

Use this

```
$("#buttonMenue").click(function(evt) {
   evt.preventDefault();
});
```